# Select all rows from 2 similar tables

Tags: c#, linq, join, gridview

Our DB Designer contractor has a database with table: ActualUses and an intermediary/temp table: EstimatedUses. The tables are the exact same except for the PK. (ActualUsesKey for ActualUses, and EstimatedUsesKey for EstimatedUses). All other columns match name and datatype.

I am tasked with displaying all rows from both tables in a GridView.

The tables link into a couple other tables to pull names over ID's so I have to create an anonymous type when using LINQ. Is there a way to pull everything I want in one LINQ query or would I have to do something like grab each table separately, load them into a DataTable then bind that table to the GridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Union (using C# Interactive window):

```
> public class AClass { public string A { get; set; } public int B { get; set; } }
> public class BClass { public string A { get; set; } public int C { get; set; } }
> var x = new List<AClass> { new AClass { A = "a", B = 1 }, new AClass { A = "B", B = 2 } };
> var y = new List<BClass> { new BClass { A = "C", C = 3 }, new BClass { A = "D", C = 4 } };
> var z = (from item in x select new { A = item.A, B = item.B }).Union(from item in y select new { A = item.A, B = item.C });
> z
UnionIterator { \{ A = "a", B = 1 }, \{ A = "B", B = 2 }, \{ A = "C", B = 3 }, \{ A = "D", B = 4 } }
```

You should be able to adapt that to your specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to make a ViewModel class, to contain the representations of your table columns, to use Join on your LinQ query and Group By if you want multiple rows by column. I also suggest later making the display information for your ViewModel.

Metadata:

```
public class TablesMetadata{
    [Display(Name = "Field 1")]
    public int table1Field1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Field 2")]
    public string table2Field1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Field 3")]
    public double table3Field1 { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(TablesMetadata))]
public class TablesViewModel{
    public int table1Field1{ get; set; }
    public string table2Field1 { get; set; }
    public double table3Field1 { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your Controller:

```
IQueryable<TablesViewModel> tables = (from t1 in context.table1
                                      from t2 in context.table2
                                      from t3 in context.table3
                                      from au in context.ActualUses
                                      join eu in context.EstimadedUses on au.ActualUsesKey equals eu.EstimatedUsesKey
                                      where //where clause
                                      select new TablesViewModel{
                                          table1Field1 = t1.table1Field1,
                                          table2Field1 = t2.table2Field1,
                                          table3Field1 = t3.table3Field1
                                      });

return View(tables.ToList());
```

Then your View type would be the full name of your ViewModel:

```
@model IEnumerable<namespace.Models.ViewModels.TablesViewModel>
```